# Is it 'everything seems okay' or 'everything seemed okay'?

Tags: difference, past-tense, present-tense

It's in the past. What's the difference between **everything seems** and **everything seemed**?

Answer (score 1):

But

> Everything seems

is about the present: what perceptions are right now, at this instant.

> Everything seemed

is about the past.

Why in the world do you think both are about the past?